# Structured Schema Matching

Tags: python, fb-hydra

I have problem using Structured Config as schema for yaml's. Is it possible to get the help with minimal working example?

Here is the working setup:

config/config.yaml

```
cd: x

defaults:
#   - config
  - source:
    - s3
    - filesystem
```

config/source/s3.yaml

```
# @package source.s3
  
bucket: bckt
key_id: 12xx345
secret_id: asdf345fa
```

config/source/filesystem.yaml

```
# @package source.filesystem

path: /mnt/docs/asdf
```

notebooks/hydra-test.ipynb

```
with initialize(version_base=None, config_path="../config"):
    cfg = compose(config_name="config")

print(cfg)
```

> {'source': {'s3': {'bucket': 'bckt', 'key_id': '12xx345', 'secret_id': 'asdf345fa'}, 'filesystem': {'path': '/mnt/docs/asdf'}}, 'cd': 'x'}

I'm fine with getting a list of sources here, not neccesarily a dictionary. Something like

> 'source':  [{'s3': {'bucket': 'bckt', 'key_id': '12xx345', 'secret_id': 'asdf345fa'}}, {'filesystem': {'path': '/mnt/docs/asdf'}}],

is more than fine. It's only important to be able to add or remove sources from the dictionary or list; not to have predetermined set of used sources.

Note, I can't use `@hydra.main` in the notebook! I tried migrating the example above to the structured config. I started with:

test_configs/config_schema.py

```
@dataclass
class Config:
    defaults: List[Any] = field(default_factory=lambda: [])
    cd: str = MISSING

cs = ConfigStore.instance()
cs.store(name="base_config", node=Config)
```

notebooks/hydra_structured_gradual.ipynb

```
from test_configs.config_schema import Config
from hydra import compose, initialize


with initialize(version_base=None, config_path='../config_gradual'):
    cfg = compose(config_name="base_config", overrides=['Config=config'])
print(cfg)
```

> {'cd': '???'}

I want to be able to build up config_schema.py to something like this:

```
@dataclass
class Database:
    driver: str
    user: str
    password: str

@dataclass
class Source:
    pass

@dataclass
class S3Source(Source):
    bucket: str
    key_id: str
    secret_id: str

@dataclass
class FileSystemSource(Source):
    path: Path

@dataclass
class Config:
    defaults: List[Any] = field(default_factory=lambda: [{
        'source': 's3'
    }])

    db: Database = MISSING
    cd: str = MISSING
    ef: list[str] = MISSING
    source: Source = MISSING

@dataclass
class Other:
    name: bool
    surname: bool

cs = ConfigStore.instance()
cs.store(name="base_config", node=Config)
cs.store(name="base_other", node=Other)
cs.store(group="source", name="base_filesystem", node=FileSystemSource)
cs.store(group="source", name="base_s3", node=S3Source)
```

and after adding correct default section to the configs (to take care of [this update](https://hydra.cc/docs/1.0/tutorials/structured_config/schema/)), run it like

notebooks/hydra_structured.ipynb

```
# All imports skipped
with initialize(version_base=None, config_path='../config'):
    cfg = compose(config_name="base_config")
```

Can someone help me complete this example, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should specify the appropriate package for the schemas:

```py
cs.store(group="source", 
         name="base_filesystem", 
         node=FileSystemSource, 
         package="source.filesystem")
```

One tip I have is to test using `@hydra.main()` while you are debugging this. this would enable you to use the debug facilities mentioned [here](https://hydra.cc/docs/advanced/defaults_list/#debugging-the-defaults-list) to better understand how the config is composed.

Comment: Thank you! I missed the 'package' argument. Also, I used notebooks to execute step by step. I will try going with @hydra.main() from now on.

Comment: I have a problem how to insert "s3" or "filesystem" tag between source and content of the file. I want to get something like this: `'source': [{'s3': {'bucket': 'bckt', 'key_id': '12xx345', 'secret_id': 'asdf345fa'}}`; instead of something like `'source': {'bucket': 'bckt', 'key_id': '12xx345', 'secret_id': 'asdf345fa'}`. Could you help by extending on the example, please?

Comment: Composing lists is not supported well. I suggest you revert to pure dictionaries and handle it at runtime. You said you were okay with getting a dict and not a list. About placing configs in specific paths in the config, you can use the package header.  For Schemas use the package parameter when you add it to the config store.

I will try to find some time to fix your example but it might take a while.

Comment: I have just managed to create a minimal but complex enough example to make this work. Do you think I could add it to the documentation or example list?

Comment: You can add it as a discussion in the repo. If there is enough interest maybe we can add it as a supported example. I think between the Structure Configs tutorials and the "Selecting multiple configs from a Config Group" page, there is enough.